# tomcat7 maven plugin WebApplicationInitializer error

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I created project using maven.
Later I connected and set plugin maven tomcat.
I try run project and all is ok. Tomcat run correctly, I can see view of my project in browser. And now I have to set my dispatcher-servlet.xml, and I want to do it in this way:

```
package com.myproject;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class SpringWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.register(ApplicationContextConfig.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(
                "SpringDispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

    }
}
```

After I did it and set pom.xml I see this exception when I use

> mvn tomcat7:run

:

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ApplicationAnnotations2]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ApplicationAnnotations2]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer cannot be cast to javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getServletContainerInitializer(ContextConfig.java:1670)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1562)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1270)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

Jan 09, 2015 12:36:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:341)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:1238)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:592)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.584 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-01-09T00:36:25+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) on project ApplicationAnnotations2: Could not start Tomcat: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]: A child container failed during start -> [Help 1]
```

My pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>ApplicationAnnotations</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>ApplicationAnnotations Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <spring.version>4.1.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>ApplicationAnnotations</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
          <server>tomcatserver</server>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

when I use `mvn tomcat7:redeploy` i can see this one:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:redeploy (default-cli) on project ApplicationAnnotations2: Tomcat return http status error: 401, Reason Phrase: Unauthorized:
[ERROR] <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
[ERROR] <html>
[ERROR] <head>
[ERROR] <title>401 Unauthorized</title>
[ERROR] <style type="text/css">
[ERROR] <!--
[ERROR] BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;font-size:12px;}
[ERROR] H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;}
[ERROR] PRE, TT {border: 1px dotted #525D76}
[ERROR] A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}
[ERROR] -->
[ERROR] </style>
[ERROR] </head>
[ERROR] <body>
[ERROR] <h1>401 Unauthorized</h1>
[ERROR] <p>
[ERROR] You are not authorized to view this page. If you have not changed
[ERROR] any configuration files, please examine the file
[ERROR] <tt>conf/tomcat-users.xml</tt> in your installation. That
[ERROR] file must contain the credentials to let you use this webapp.
[ERROR] </p>
[ERROR] <p>
[ERROR] For example, to add the <tt>manager-gui</tt> role to a user named
[ERROR] <tt>tomcat</tt> with a password of <tt>s3cret</tt>, add the following to the
[ERROR] config file listed above.
[ERROR] </p>
[ERROR] <pre>
[ERROR] &lt;role rolename="manager-gui"/&gt;
[ERROR] &lt;user username="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="manager-gui"/&gt;
[ERROR] </pre>
[ERROR] <p>
[ERROR] Note that for Tomcat 7 onwards, the roles required to use the manager
[ERROR] application were changed from the single <tt>manager</tt> role to the
[ERROR] following four roles. You will need to assign the role(s) required for
[ERROR] the functionality you wish to access.
[ERROR] </p>
[ERROR] <ul>
[ERROR] <li><tt>manager-gui</tt> - allows access to the HTML GUI and the status
[ERROR] pages</li>
[ERROR] <li><tt>manager-script</tt> - allows access to the text interface and the
[ERROR] status pages</li>
[ERROR] <li><tt>manager-jmx</tt> - allows access to the JMX proxy and the status
[ERROR] pages</li>
[ERROR] <li><tt>manager-status</tt> - allows access to the status pages only</li>
[ERROR] </ul>
[ERROR] <p>
[ERROR] The HTML interface is protected against CSRF but the text and JMX interfaces
[ERROR] are not. To maintain the CSRF protection:
[ERROR] </p>
[ERROR] <ul>
[ERROR] <li>Users with the <tt>manager-gui</tt> role should not be granted either
[ERROR] the <tt>manager-script</tt> or <tt>manager-jmx</tt> roles.</li>
[ERROR] <li>If the text or jmx interfaces are accessed through a browser (e.g. for
[ERROR] testing since these interfaces are intended for tools not humans) then
[ERROR] the browser must be closed afterwards to terminate the session.</li>
[ERROR] </ul>
[ERROR] <p>
[ERROR] For more information - please see the
[ERROR] <a href="/docs/manager-howto.html">Manager App HOW-TO</a>.
[ERROR] </p>
[ERROR] </body>
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] </html>
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

my maven settings.xml

```
<server>
    <id>tomcatserver</id>
    <username>admin</username>
    <password>admin</password>
</server>
```

my apache tomcat-users.xml

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
<role rolename="manager-status"/>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<role rolename="admin-script"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui, manager-script, manager-jmx, manager-status, admin-gui, admin-script"/>
```

but with settings all have to be all right because with other projects where exist dispatcher-servlet.xml all work perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very likely because of the servlet-api jar being packaged with the application, try changing the scope of the servlet-api to provided and it should be work:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version> 
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your problem may be caused by:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Tomcat 7 implements the servlet 3.0 specification.
Try changing the version to 3.0.